# Azure AD authentication, giving error unauthorized_client for react, .Net core web api project

Tags: .net, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm testing the example in following GitHub repository.
[Azure AD for React Redux .Net core](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-obo)

I've selected the Supported account types as "Accounts in this organizational directory only " when registering both client and API apps. But when executing it gives following error when trying to login.

"We're unable to complete your request
unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908."](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.%22)

can anyone please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you are using a Microsoft Account(MSA) to login your client app, but it is not enabled for that.

To allow your client app to be logged in with an MSA, you need to choose the `Supported account types` with the third option or fourth option like below when you create it.

[image]

To change the setting for an existing AD App, navigate to the `Manifest` blade of it in the portal, find the [`signInAudience`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#signinaudience-attribute) attribute, set it with `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` or `PersonalMicrosoftAccount`, they correspond to the above two options.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the heads up. I need to allow only for the users within the organization. That's why I selected "Accounts in this organizational directory only" option. How can I make it success with "Accounts in this organizational directory only" option?

Comment: @Thanushka Well, if so, you could not use a personal account to login, e.g. outlook, hotmail account, you can just use a work account to login, if you don‘t have one, just create one in your AAD tenant(the client app located), follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory#add-a-new-user), the user created is the work account, i.e. with the format like `xxxx@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`.

Comment: I want to use an work account. That's why I've selected Accounts in this organizational directory only. But it give the error "We're unable to complete your request unauthorized_client:". If I select "Personal Microsoft accounts only" it works fine. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Thanushka Make sure you specify the tenant-id in the request url you used to login `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`, then use a work account to login.

Comment: Thanks it worked.  Had to set      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ {tenent-id}"